# AWK: Sum of values in a column based on entries in another column

Tags: shell-script, awk

I would like to sum numerical values listed in the third column of the table below based on entries were given in the first column of the same table. The table content is as follows:

```
John|Login|2
Mary|Login|10
Mary|Payroll|100
John|Login|200
John|Logout|10
Mary|Payroll|10
```

The expected outcome is as follows:

```
John|Login|202
John|Logout|10
Mary|Login|10
Mary|Payroll|110
```

How can I use `awk` to get this output?

Comment: Very similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471251/subtotal-of-rows and other similar questions.

Comment: Certainly, awk can do math. That's not your question, though. What's your question? What is the operation?

Comment: Wanted to sum-up the values in the 3rd column based on the values in 1st and 2nd column.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/471325/edit) so that it's all together; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command worked for me. it should work for you :

```
     awk -F '|' '{a[$1"|"$2"|"]+= $3} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' filename | sort -k 1,1
John|Login| 202
John|Logout| 10
Mary|Login| 10
Mary|Payroll| 110
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `awk` installed, you don't have to use another tool `sort` to set the order right, but you can do it in `awk` itself. You can set the way the array traversal is done by setting a special variable `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`. See [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with `gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)

In your case though, you can set it to sort by the index in ascending order

```
awk -vFS="|" -vOFS="|"  '{ 
                             primaryKey=($1 FS $2)
                         }{ 
                             db[primaryKey]+=$3; next 
                         } END { 
                             PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
                             for(key in db) 
                                 print key, db[key] 
                         }' file
```